# How can I synchronise data between an external server from Intranet server?

Tags: php, database, proxy, intranet

I wrote a script which shows status of live/online hubs in our college intranet which are not accessible from outside as we are behind the proxies. 
So, I would to ask, How can I data in External server from Intranet server automatically ?

Comment: You should add some code and show what you have tried or give a concrete example of what you would like to do. I don't think that your question will be answered like this.

Answer (score 0):

Can this help? Maybe an HTTP tunnel?

> HTTP tunneling is a technique by which communications performed using
>   various network protocols are encapsulated using the HTTP protocol,
>   the network protocols in question usually belonging to the TCP/IP
>   family of protocols. The HTTP protocol therefore acts as a wrapper for
>   a channel that the network protocol being tunneled uses to
>   communicate.
>
> The HTTP stream with its covert channel is termed an HTTP tunnel.
>
> HTTP tunnel software consists of client-server HTTP tunneling
>   applications that integrate with existing application software,
>   permitting them to be used in conditions of restricted network
>   connectivity including firewalled networks, networks behind proxy
>   servers, and network address translation.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_tunnel